# How to get data from RS-485 connected by USB

Tags: java, usb, javafx-8, rs485

I need to read data from some Data Aggregator Device over RS-485 interface by USB port (USB-to-RS-485 converter used) for the Desktop App on JavaFX, so I have stacked on checking connection and getting proper values.

Data Aggregator Device collects information about produced current, power etc. from PV-module (Solar Energy). This device has the only RS-485 port. As I read from a documentation, it uses Modbus RTU protocol (with settings: 9600-8N1).

To be honest, It's my first experience with working on COM-ports and Devices. That is why I don't know even am I correctly connect pins. I read a lot of things related with RS-485, Modbus. But, still, I am on the first steps.

So, I use simple UTP cable to connect. And what I have done:

1. [This is how I connect USB-to-RS485 converter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzrLy.jpg)
2. [And this is
       about Data Aggregator Device](https://pp.vk.me/c837628/v837628592/1dc37/d7NfEddewCE.jpg)

Windows found virtual "COM3" port, after connecting USB to PC. Then I try to check connection with Terminal 1.9 by Bray. I try to send something. And as receiving messages it sent me some data also. However, it doesn't mean that everything connected well. Also terminal shows me some **FRAME ERROR**.
I know, that Modbus protocol based on "master-slave" scheme. Therefore, PC as a client is "Master" and device as a server is "Slave". I have to send some request to the slave to get some expected response. But, how?!
 Please, check my connections! I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

RS-485 is differential and requires just two wires, you can safely remove the ground wire (GND). Then, connect the wires to R+ and R- on your USB-to-RS485 converter

Done that, may I ask you how you tried to send something? Modbus requires a final byte, the CRC which is hard to determine by hand. Did you create a valid modbus packet?

A valid modbus packet requires a receiver address, the payload length, the data itself and the final CRC

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply!
I've removed the GND. So, if I understand correctly, instead of A and B on the USB converter, I have to connect wires to R+ and R-? And what about the device?Should I have to do the same?

Comment: I've just sent anything. Of course, it is not a good case. I've just tried to see a reaction of virtual port. I don't know how to send. I know that packet include header, PDU, checksum. It will be great if you will show some basic example how to send proper packet! 

P.S.: I want to make my project with Java, so is it possible to make it with java? I found a lot of libraries. But what is the best one?

P.S.S:  http://forum.easyelectronics.ru/download/file.php?id=30525&sid=a73ca588be24d221b7ffe32118de379a&mode=view What I've done in Terminal

Comment: first you need to find out the exact packet format as expected by the solar inverter. Check on the manual, it should be there

Comment: I found from their manual only these:

__The generating information of the third part includes below items.
PV Module: DC voltage, DC current, RT power, RT temperature, status notes
Combiner Box: string voltage, DC current, string power, status notes
Inverter: system voltage & current, system power production, status notes
Ammeter: power production, system current
Environment Monitor: wind scale, illumination intensity, temperature, humidity__

Also, they include connection settings: 9600-8N1. And that is all. This is my device http://www.gnetek.com/en/product.php?tid=8

Comment: exact model of the inverter? best way would be having the proprietary software run and sniff the packets, then have a look at the packets and work out the protocol, it's surely a variant of modbus

Comment: To be honest, I don't have an inverter just PV modules, optimizers and data processing device. PV modules connected to optimizers and to hand-made electrical load with lamps. Optimizers connected to data processing device(DAD) wireless and they send information to it. Then every time collecting information DAD can send them to their own WEB application.

Comment: But my task, to make the desktop app to talk with DAD autonomy, without their web-service. But you've seen my problems

Comment: do you have the proprietary software to read the devices via rs485?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Does it mean that there is no another way?

Comment: if you found out it's modbus then try to send some modbus packet, I recommend this software here -> http://www.simplymodbus.ca/manual.htm

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about java, but if you do have specification of devices protocol, you can surely use terminal program to send message to modbus and read messages back. That way you will have protocol tested and it shouldn't be to hard to make custom software later. But until you can send message and get back meaningful message using terminal software I recommend you to stick to it.

This youtube video will give basic knowledge needed about modbus RTU packet format: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvRD2UvrHjE

The most difficult part is calculating CRC every time. But luckily you can download Docklight terminal. It actually has an option to calculate CRC automatically for modbus and add it at last positions of the packet. 
You can download free version at their homepage.

docklight.de

It is very simple to use. Same as Bray terminal you used.. And here is example of how to set up modbus CRC  calculation for every package. 
https://docklight.de/manual/sendingmodbuscommandswithc.htm

I know they also have great support.
Once you successfully send message to device and get answer, things will get much easier because you will understand how protocol actually works. Modbus RTU is very mature protocol, but it is still used because many existing systems use it and it is very simple to add it to some device. All device needs is Serial port (UART) to connect to modbus. So it is not that hard to understand it and use it. Just check out explanation video and terminal specifically adopted for modbus that I gave links in this message.

Comment: Thank you very much @Vladimir! It is a very important information at the very beginning. Because I did not understand how it works and broke my mind every day :) Unfortunately, the company which made this device don't want to share the specification of protocol. That's why my next steps was declined.